# Иерархия файловой системы Symfony

Tags: symfony2, symfony, php-frameworks

Как правильно расположить файлы на Symfony?

Например, я расположил `AdminBundle` в отдельной папке

[image: Админ]

Правильно ли расположены бандлы? Где расположить последующие бандлы, например, `MediaBundle`.

Answer (score 1):

Лучшие практики по структуре приложения описаны здесь: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#application-bundles

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

Группируйте бандлы в директории если они относятся к какой-то определённой части системы, давайте им осмысленные имена, не создавайте божественных бандлов (по аналогии с антипаттерном god object), в остальном делайте так, как считаете правильным. Абстрактный пример:

Допустим есть приложение, которое содержит два разных API, два бэкенда (две разные админки), бизнес логику, один фронтенд. Ниже структура внутри директории src:

```
YourProjName
- DomainBundle // бандл только лишь интегрирует бизнес логику в среду симфони, саму логику в бандл добавлять не следует
- Frontend
- - MainBundle // главный бандл, интегрирует другие бандлы фронтенда
- - Feature1Bundle // какая-то фича, которая может быть использована в других проектах или легко отключена
- - Feature2Bundle // ...
- Backend
- - CustomersBackend
- - - MainBudnle // здесь всё собирается воедино
- - - UserBundle // например, расширение для FOSUsereBundle, либо интеграция пользователей из домена в данный бэкенд
- - - MediaBundle // расширение медиа бандла
- - CompanyBackend
- - - ... // принцип аналогичен
- Api
- - PublicRestApiBundle // при необходимости можно разделить версии API на разные бандлы
- - WhateverApiBundle
```

Если бандл предполагается делать публичным, то к нему особенно жёсткие требования по соответствию [стандартам Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html). Но поначалу не стоит об этом слишком долго задумываться, с опытом работы в Symfony придёт и понимание где что должно находиться.